# C calculation of the gradient of a multidimensional function. (partial derivatives)

Tags: c, math, multidimensional-array, gradient

[image]

[image]

I tried to implement an algorithm for calculating the gradient, but I can't even figure out whether it works correctly or not, because I don't know how to calculate it even with my hands.

I have attached the material on which I tried to make an implementation of the algorithm. I would be very grateful if someone could give an example of the input data and the result that should turn out, because I really want to figure it out. And also I would like to know what I have incorrectly prescribed in my program.

Thank you in advance. Because I'm really stuck on this and I can't move from a dead place.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return (x * x );
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double del = 0.1;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fx;
    fx = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fy;
    fy = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* grad;
    grad = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];
        fx[i] = f(x[i]);
    }
    double a = 1 / del;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = y[i] + del;
        fy[i] = f(y[i]);
        grad[i] = a * (fy[i] - fx[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf ", grad[i]);
    }

}
```

UPD:

```
double f(double arr[], int size)
{
    int a = sizeof(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i];
    }
    return *arr;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double del = 0.1;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fx;
    fx = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fy;
    fy = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* grad;
    grad = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];
        fx[i] = f(x,n);
    }
    double a = 1 / del;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = y[i] + del;
        fy[i] = f(y,n);
        grad[i] = a * (fy[i] - fx[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf ", grad[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get `return (x * x );` from?

Comment: @4386427 I'm sorry I didn't really understand your question. I call this function sometimes in the main.

Comment: Why do you do that? Nothing in the task description says that

Comment: Unrelated: I suggest simplifying the allocation/deallocation by putting x, y, fx, fy and grad in a struct and allocating `n` number of such structs instead. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/sP5vKjq9K)

Comment: @4386427 why is that? x is an array of values f(x) is a function. And how do you think I should look for partial derivatives?

Comment: which partial derivatives? your function has only one argument

Comment: @numzero aww..and then how do I make it look like in the very top example?(the first two pictures)I'm completely confused.. :(

Comment: @numzero I have to count the value of the function from each argument, right? i mean x1 , x2....

Comment: The function in the “Gradient calculation algorithm” has an argument that is a vector or, equivalently, a point in a multidimensional space (which may be implemented in C as an array). The **x** in f(**x**) is a vector of multiple values. The `f` in your code is not such a function; it takes only a single-valued argument. Rewrite your code to use an `f` that takes an array as an argument. (C does not pass arrays as arguments, but you can write the code as if it does. Array parameters are automatically adjusted to be pointers, and array arguments are automatically converted to pointers.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil is that the only problem?that is, if I pass an argument in the form of an array to the function, will everything work correctly?

Comment: Once you have done that, the idea of the algorithm is that the vector **x** is a base point that is copied into **y** and moved slightly in one dimension. Then the difference between f(**y**) and f(**x**) is used to estimate the gradient of the function in that dimension. Repeating that for each dimension produces a vector **g** that approximates the gradient of the function considering all dimensions.

Comment: You need to rewrite more than just the calls to `f`. There is no reason for your arrays `fx` and `fy`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm sorry, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried to rewrite it. :(

Comment: @EricPostpischil please correct it if you can, I'm already redrawing the program in every possible way, but I get all the garbage in output...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this by hand for a single function before you worry about a vector of functions.

Assume you have one independent variable `x` and one function `y = f(x)`:

1. Pick a value for x[i]
2. Calculate y(x[i]) = f(x[i])
3. Calculate x[i+1] = x[i] + delta
4. Calculate y(x[i+1]) = f(x[i+1])
5. The forward different approximation of the derivative at x[i] is (y(x[i+1]) - y(x[i])/delta.

There are other ways to approximate the derivative, but this is a start.

Once this works for a single function it's easy to see how to extend it to a vector of functions: turn all those subscripts to vectors.

You should understand that

1. independent variables x are a vector
2. dependent functions y are a vector
3. derivatives of y w.r.t. x are expressed as an m x n *matrix*, not a
   vector:

   dy[i]/dx[j] for i = 1 to m, j = 1 to n

There are n independent variables x and m dependent functions y.